# Generating code (input form for text boxes) using PHP...loop?

Tags: php, forms, loops, input, while-loop

So I'm learning PHP and am just adding a date select feature to some text input boxes class ='tcal'. Now all the input boxes are the same but only some of them have the tcal feature but all of them need it.

I know I can just manually enter it in each field but in the spirit of learning I was wondering if there was a way to add class = 'tcal' to all the input forms possibly using a while loop?

heres an example with the first group of input forms having the tcal and the second group not. Anyway I can accomplihs this using PHP?

```
<td><input class='tcal' type="text" name="txtG1D1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG1P1" value="P-"></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG1RD1" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG1RT1" value="00.0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='tcal' type="text" name="txtG1D2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG1P2" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG1RD2" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG1RT2" value="00.0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='tcal' type="text" name="txtG1D3" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG1P3" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG1RD3" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG1RT3" value="00.0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='tcal' type="text" name="txtG1D4" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG1P4" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG1RD4" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG1RT4" value="00.0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='tcal' type="text" name="txtG1D5" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG1P5" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG1RD5" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG1RT5" value="00.0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input class='tcal' type="text" name="txtG1D6" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG1P6" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG1RD6" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG1RT6" value="00.0"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">Group #2 <input type="text" name="txtGroup2" size="80" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2D1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2P1" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG2RD1" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG2RT1" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2D2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2P2" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG2RD2" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG2RT2" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2D3" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2P3" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG2RD3" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG2RT3" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2D4" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2P4" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG2RD4" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG2RT4" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2D5" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2P5" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG2RD5" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG2RT5" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2D6" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtG2P6" value=""></td>
    <td><input size="100" type="text" name="txtG2RD6" value=""></td>
    <td>$<input type="text" name="txtG2RT6" value=""></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you can use jquery for that.

Comment: PHP operates on the server when you're creating the page. If the page is already created, and you want to modify it, you have to do this with Javascript on the client.

Comment: use jquery ui calendar popup

Comment: I'm not looking for another way to do it per-se...more along the lines of some code to generate multiple repetitive code. (enter in a calender popup multiple times so I dont have to manually enter it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it with PHP, you could do something like:

```
<?php
    $groups = 2; //number of groups
    $rows = 4; //number of rows per group
    $tcalS = Array( 0 ); //groups that should be marked tcal, 0 is group 1

?>
    <table>

<?php
        for( $g = 0; $g < $groups; ++$g )
        {
?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4">Group #<?php echo $g; ?><input type="text" name="txtGroup<?php echo $g; ?>" size="80" value=""></td>
            </tr>
<?php
            for( $r=0; $r < $rows; ++$r )
            {
                addRow( $r, $g, in_array( $g, $tcalS ) );
            }
        }
?>

    </table>
<?php


    function addRow( $rowNum, $groupNum, $bIsTcal )
    {
        $nameD = 'txtG'.$groupNum.'D'.$rowNum;
        $nameRD = 'txtG'.$groupNum.'RD'.$rowNum;
        $nameRT = 'txtG'.$groupNum.'RT'.$rowNum;
        $nameP = 'txtG'.$groupNum.'P'.$rowNum;
?>
        <tr>
            <td><input <?php echo $bIsTcal ? 'class="tcal"' : ''; ?> type="text" name="<?php echo $nameD; ?>" value=""></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="<?php echo $nameP; ?>" value="P-"></td>
            <td><input size="100" type="text" name="" value="<?php echo $nameRD; ?>"></td>
            <td>$<input type="text" name="<?php echo $nameRT; ?>" value="00.0"></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }

?>
```

but there are definitely other/better ways.